# Where do nuget packages via project.json in asp.net 5 get downloaded to?

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core, t4

Looking at asp.net 5 and referencing Nuget packages via project.json:

When the project.json file is updated, the libraries are referenced, however we do these get downloaded to.

I have T4 templates that reference libraries and want to reference the same ones and need to know where they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They get downloaded under

```
c:\Users\[username]\.dnx\packages
```

assuming your Users folder is on c drive